# How do I click and drag an Image from the point that I clicked it, and not at the center in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 272
height = 552

white = 255,255,255

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption('War Games')

Map = pygame.image.load("SPEMap.jpg"); pygame.Surface((800,552))
rect = Map.get_rect(); rect.center = (400,286)

stop = False

while not stop:

    gameDisplay.blit(Map, rect)


    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()


    pygame.display.update()
```

Here I have an image of a map that is larger than the screen. I have it set up so that when I click on the image, the image moves so that the center of the image is under my mouse, and then I can drag the image around. I was wondering how I could make so that I drag the image from the point that I clicked it, instead of having it jump to the center. I hope that wasn't too confusing.

Comment: Get the offset of the center from the position clicked and then use it to "un-offset" it.

Answer (score 1):

Like sshashank124 said, you need to offset the image x, y position with its width, height dimensions.  An example being:

```
imageX = mouseX - (imageWidth / 2)
imageY = mouseY - (imageHeight / 2)
```

I hope I am not reading your question wrongly.

EDIT:  The code snippet above would translate out in your program to something like the code below.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((272, 552))

mapWidth = 0  # MUST FILL IN SIZE
mapHeight = 0 # MUST FILL IN SIZE
gameMap = pygame.image.load("SPEMap.jpg")
mapRect = map.get_rect()

stop = False
while not stop:
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        if mapRect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            mapRect.x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - (mapWidth / 2)
            mapRect.x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - (mapWidth / 2)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            stop = True

    gameDisplay.blit(gameMap, mapRect)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

If worthy, please show your appreciation by choosing as the Best Answer. :)

Comment: How do I get the mouse x coordinates and mouse y coordinates seperately

Comment: @RomanFormicola:  You already have separate values (`pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0/1]`).  See the answer above for more details I've added.

Comment: Isn't that the point?  I must be misunderstanding something greatly.

Answer (score 0):

pygame.mouse.get_pos() returns a tuple of the mouse x and y position

you get the mouse positions seperately like so:

```
mouse_x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]
```

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't been able to successfully apply your help. I am very new to python, and it would be great if someone could be more literal in there advice. I apologize for the inconvenience I am quite the novice.